# in AndEngine mEngine.setScene() function is not working

Tags: android, andengine

Ive been trying to get my app to change from one scene to another. what i do is onLoadScene() i direct it to a method which has a scene, and what im trying to do is to set another scene which is in another method... but what i get is the sprite from the first scene stuck on the screen !

can someone help me in teaching me how to change from one scene to another in the same class.

here are my codes:

```
@Override
public Scene onLoadScene() {
    return splashGame();
}

private Scene splashGame(){
    final Scene sceneGameSplash = new Scene();

    sceneGameSplash.setBackgroundEnabled(false);

    System.out.println("pls work 1");
    final Sprite splashSprite = new Sprite(0,0, this.gameSplashScreenRegion);

    sceneGameSplash.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(3f, true, new ITimerCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
            sceneGameSplash.unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);

            System.out.println("pls work");


            splashUnjum();
          }
    }));

    splashSprite.setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    splashSprite.setHeight(display.getHeight());
    splashSprite.setWidth(display.getWidth());

    sceneGameSplash.attachChild(splashSprite);


    return sceneGameSplash;

}

private Scene splashUnjum(){

    final Scene sceneUnjumSplash = new Scene();
    this.mEngine.setScene(sceneUnjumSplash);

     System.out.println("pls work 2");
    final Sprite splashUnjumSprite = new Sprite(0,0,this.gamevedaSplashScreenRegion);
    splashUnjumbleSprite.setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    splashUnjumSprite.setHeight(display.getHeight());
    splashUnjumSprite.setWidth(display.getWidth());

    sceneUnjumSplash.attachChild(splashUnjumSprite);

    sceneUnjumSplash.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(3f, true, new ITimerCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
            sceneUnjumSplash.unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);

            System.out.println("pls work yo");

            mainMenu();
        }
    }));


    return sceneUnjumSplash;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the issue, but I think you should remove this line from splashUnjum()

```
this.mEngine.setScene(sceneUnjumSplash);
```

replace the call to splashUnjum() with

```
this.mEngine.setScene(splashUnjum());
```

One other thing you should do is insure that the change happens on the updateThread